# thead and tbody have a line of space I can't get rid of

Tags: html, css, html-table, antd

I am trying to eliminate the space between the `thead` and `tbody`.

I am using styled-components on top of Antd UI framework.

From what I can tell it's not a border, margin, or padding. I can't even select the Whiteline between them.

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

const StyledTable = styled(Table)`
  thead th {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.black1};
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
  }
  thead tr th:hover {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.secondary} !important;
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
  }
  tbody.ant-table-tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.primaryHover};
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
  }
  tbody {
    tr {
      td {
        border: none;
        background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.black2};
        color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.85);
        &:hover, &:focus {
          color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
        }
      }
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) td{
      background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.black3};
    }
  }
  .ant-table-cell{
    div span svg {
      color: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
      fill: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
    }
    a, a:visited, a:hover{
      color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
    }
  }`;
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting `th{border:none;}`

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work

Comment: What about `thead{border:none !important}` and also try to use `!important` may be there is some style which needs to be overwritten as its not working so its hard to find that

Comment: it is not a border. I can tell when I do inspect in dev tools. I have tried all variations of borders with no change.

Comment: can you please create its working example either in codepen or stackblitz i have some hack in my mind which in need to apply on that as you are using `https://ant.design/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. Just simply add this to the style component.
I had forgotten to just simply remove the body or the head to discover first where the line was coming from.
After that, it was easier to navigate in dev tools and see the border was coming from the row headers.

```
   .ant-table-thead > tr > th {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For remove border from table header you need to replace the default css styles:

```
.ant-table-thead > tr > th {
  border-bottom-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black3};
}
```

Online example:

[image: Edit Basic Usage - antd@4.9.4 (forked)]